# Listview and array adapter and remove

Tags: android, listview

I created an adapter

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Watch>
```

overriding

```
public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Watch> values){     
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);        
    this.context = context;
}
```

and

```
private View createOneView(){
...
}
```

Then i do

```
 MyArrayAdapter myAdapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, getAllWatches());
 ... //DO some stuff here
 myAdapter.remove(getAllWatches().get(2));
 myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The watch is still not removed. I suspect that objects are removed only if ther are `==` and not `.equal()`, or am I just missing something more trivial?

Comment: are you trying to removing something from getAllWatches()?

Comment: I did't remove anything from the array. I mean, for sure the element 2 would be removed, but in this test I just called the .remove, without modifying getAllWatches(), should I modify it instead? I don't think I should though because after initialization I guess getAllWatches() is copyed into the adapter, not just referenced by it.

Comment: Why you don't remove the watch wanted before instantiating your Adapter?

Comment: Let us say list has 1,2,3,4,5 are you trying to remove '3' from list display? I am trying to understand what you are doing here. If that is the case, I would suggest remove it from getAllWatches() before setting it to adapter.

Comment: It's a test, in real code I would .remove() the element in another place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myAdapter.getPosition(getAllWatches().get(2))` return -1, so the problem is the object is not found. ArrayAdapater uses indeed `.equals()` method. Implementing it in the appropriate way (comparingfields) everything works smoothly.

Comment: Now it is. I just needed to implement .equals in a convenient way